# Cant get jquery slideshow in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to position my slideshow into a div with a certain width and height, but for some reason it is not working. I cant get this slideshow script to not be full screen. I can't get it to be 600px width max. It just keeps taking up the whole window.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('div.gallery img').slidingGallery();
        container: $('div.gallery')
    });
</script>

<div class="gallery" style="width:800px; height:500px;">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UkU8B.jpg" class ="start"alt="rawr" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UkU8B.jpg" alt="rawr" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UkU8B.jpg" alt="rawr" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UkU8B.jpg" alt="rawr" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UkU8B.jpg" alt="rawr" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UkU8B.jpg" alt="rawr" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UkU8B.jpg" alt="rawr" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UkU8B.jpg" alt="rawr" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UkU8B.jpg" alt="rawr" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UkU8B.jpg" alt="rawr" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UkU8B.jpg" alt="rawr" />
    </div>
```

Here is a working example to see what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/fFMEg/

Here is the js for the slide script:
http://syndicatebox.com/jquery.slidingGallery-1.2.min.js

Comment: Is there any way to get the uncompressed source of that slidingGallery plugin?

Comment: Sure http://syndicatebox.com/jquery.slidingGallery-1.2.min.js

Comment: http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGallery.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling it incorrectly. Instead of this:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.gallery img').slidingGallery();
    container: $('div.gallery')
});
```

(which isn't even valid JavaScript) do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.gallery img').slidingGallery({
        container: $('div.gallery')
    });
});
```

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/fFMEg/7/) out for reference.

Comment: Okay!! that shows a difference but for some reason it still stays the same width, its jsut half of it shows now..

Comment: Please see the link I posted for an example of how to customize this plugin, all of which I learned from reading the documentation at the site you provided.